# pull data with Jsoup and write into excel file

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, jsoup

I am attempting to use jsoup in eclipse to pull data from an html table and write that dat into an excel file. I am able to pull the table data out of the html, but it is all considered one string that is difficult to write to an excel file. I am not sure if this is the correct way to pull the information but this is my current code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Document document;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("https://companiesmarketcap.com/usa/largest-companies-in-the-usa-by-market-cap/?page=1/").get();
    

    Elements trs = document.select("td");
    for (Element NEW : trs ) {
    Elements table = NEW.getElementsByTag("td");    
    Element td =  table.first();
    String TA = td.text();
    
    
    }

    
    }
    
    
     catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This gets me my table data, but I am not able to adjust this data to put it into an excel doc. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code. How do you want to adjust the data, and what difficulty are you having doing it?

Comment: So my String TA that I get from pulling from the html is a long string of data from the website like:                                                                                                              
1Apple AAPL$2.815 T$172.55-0.14%USA2Microsoft MSFT$2.245 T$299.50-0.12%USA3Alphabet (Google) GOOG$1.818 T$2,7500.78%USA4Amazon AMZN$1.608 T$3,1621.02%USA                                                                                                                   I want to put this data in an excel sheet but I am not sure how to split this string.

Comment: When I run your code, that isn't what I get at all. TD is `1`, then `Apple AAPL`, then `$2.815 T`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific to select the individual elements so you can format them the way you want... Keep studying the Jsoup documentation and CSS selectors... I kept it simple, the code below works so you can copy and paste the result into excel.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://companiesmarketcap.com/usa/largest-companies-in-the-usa-by-market-cap/?page=1/").get();

        Elements thList = document.select("table > thead > tr > th"); // Get table column headers
        for (Element th : thList) {
            sb.append(th.text()).append("\t"); // Append table header's text content + tab separator
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); // To delete the last tab
        sb.append("\n"); // Append new line to end of header's content

        Elements trList = document.select("table > tbody > tr"); // Get all rows in the table body
        for (Element tr : trList) {
            Elements tdList = tr.select("td"); // Get column details
            for (Element td : tdList) {
                sb.append(td.text()).append("\t"); // Append table details' text content + tab separator
            }
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1); // To delete the last tab
            sb.append("\n"); // Append new line to end of row's content
        }

        System.out.println(sb);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```